# Vuejs Disabled button when we didnt fill form

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, disabled-input

[image]

I want disable Remove button but When we fill Project Number Form area and click on Find I want to be activate Remove button I try something but it doesnt work. Can anybody help me?

!! I SOLVE IT !!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<b-form-group class="mb-0 mt-3" label-cols-lg="4">
            <button
             
              v-model ="form.ProjectNumber = '' "
                  :disabled="true" 
              class="w-100 btn btn-danger"
              size="sm"
              @click="RemoveProjectQuestion"
            > 
              Remove Project
            </button>

          </b-form-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<b-form-group class="mb-0 mt-3" label-cols-lg="4">
            <button
             
              :disabled="form.ProjectNumber ==null || form.ProjectNumber == ''"
              class="w-100 btn btn-danger"
              size="sm"
              @click="RemoveProjectQuestion"
            > 
              Remove Project
            </button>
```

I Solve It

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may try some thing like this in your button element
`v-bind:class="[condition ? {classA} : {classB}]"`

If your condition gets true add disabled class else you can pass active class to it

or vice versa based on your condition provided